# Dropzone + Laravel form in one place

Tags: forms, laravel, upload, eloquent, dropzone.js

I have a laravel project which is classifieds site and every advert should have a few photos attached to it. I have made two models with two tables in db one for adverts another for pics, relations are set properly media table has foreign key advert_id Dropzonejs used in form but URL for it pointing to function from MediaController the addition of adverts is managed by AdvertController Now the issue is in these two separate working places when I upload images I don't know advert_id value, but I cannot figure how to make users save advert first and THEN upload images. I don't want to split form on two pages but have no idea how to manipulate user to do what I need.
Here is my code for managing dropzone:

```js
$('.dropzone-stuff').dropzone({
    url: "{{ URL::to('upl') }}",
    paramName: 'file',
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    maxFiles: 5,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    clickable: true,
    dictDefaultMessage: "{{ trans('custom.drop.dictDefaultMessage') }}",
    dictFallbackMessage: "{{ trans('custom.drop.dictFallbackMessage') }}",
    dictFallbackText: "{{ trans('custom.drop.dictFallbackText') }}",
    dictInvalidFileType: "{{ trans('custom.drop.dictInvalidFileType') }}",
    dictFileTooBig: "{{ trans('custom.drop.dictFileTooBig') }}",
    dictCancelUpload: "{{ trans('custom.drop.dictCancelUpload') }}",
    dictRemoveFile: "{{ trans('custom.drop.dictRemoveFile') }}",
    dictMaxFilesExceeded: "{{ trans('custom.drop.dictMaxFilesExceeded') }}",
});
```

Here is the portion that manages upload in MediaController:

```
public function uploadImages()
    {
        if (Sentry::check()) {
            $file = Input::file('file');
            $advert_id = Advert::orderby('id', 'desc')->first()->id;
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/'.Sentry::getUser()->username.'/';
            $filename = str_random(6);
            $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = $filename.'.'.$extension;
            $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            if( $upload_success ) {
                return Response::json('success', 200);
            } else {
                return Response::json('error', 400);
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, I think there would be too much code to post everything here but I will just tell the need - I must have advert ID BEFORE upload to use it for advert_id column in media table.

Comment: Solved it by adding Session::push('files',$filename) and then referring to this session variable after creating advert. After adding links to media to db table, flush the Session.

Still think this is not how it should be done but good as a temporary solution.

Comment: Still not reliable solution, still looking for help

Answer (score 0):

The way I am tackling a similar situation is to create the Entity (Advert) first then have a second page or step for the media you plan to add to it. Since the entity exists - and can be posted to the next page where you upload your media, you can just add this to your script

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
   formData.append('advert_id', <?php echo $advert_id; ?>);
});
```

Then in your *upl* file, you can associate it there.

Comment: But how would I get advert_id if advert is not created yet? it is just a preview of advert and  advert id will be ready AFTER this step is done.